# Overlapping elements using Sticky-kit (jQuery plugin) because navbar automatically fills window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to achieve a navbar that is first stickied to the bottom of the page. No matter what height the window is, it will stick on the bottom - then I want it to be stickied on top upon scrolling.

I am able to achieve that through a jQuery library, Sticky-Kit http://leafo.net/sticky-kit/. However, all my other elements are overlapped by the navbar. I have changed the z-index of my other elements, that works but now the navbar is overlapped. Same problem, different element. Plus, it doesn't look nice as my content looks like as it goes on the navbar rather than underneath it.

The code on jsfiddle will help you get a picture of what I'm trying to achieve:
http://jsfiddle.net/u6aNX/

In the jsfiddle link above, it does not fully replicate my project but it does replicate the problem. The navbar height increase allowing other elements to be overlapped. Although on my project it does show that it increase but when I check on Chrome Dev Tools, I can see that the height of it is the same as the window.

Extra info:

- I am using Bootstrap. .navbar is from Bootstrap

Code:

HTML:

```
  <div class="navbar navbar-bottom" id="sticker">
      <div class="container">
        <a class="brand" href="https://twitter.com/duaneadam" id="duane-brand">@duaneadam</a>
          <ul class="over-nav nav">
            <li>Home</li>
            <li>About</li>
          </ul>
      </div> <!-- /container -->
</div> <!-- /navbar /navbar-bottom -->

  <div>
      <h2>Hello World!</h2>
      <p>
          Lorem ipsums here to achieve scrolling. Check jsfiddle link
      </p>
  </div>
```

CSS: (Custom, overriding Bootstrap)

```
    .navbar-bottom {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin: 0px;
}
.navbar {
    background-color: #ccff22;
}
```

JavaScript/jQuery:

```
/*
 Sticky-kit v1.0.1 | WTFPL | Leaf Corcoran 2013 | http://leafo.net
*/
(function(){var g,t;g=this.jQuery;t=g(window);g.fn.stick_in_parent=function(d){var u,k,e,r,B,h,C;null==d&&(d={});r=d.sticky_class;u=d.inner_scrolling;e=d.parent;k=d.offset_top;null==k&&(k=0);null==e&&(e=void 0);null==u&&(u=!0);null==r&&(r="is_stuck");B=function(a,d,h,v,y,l){var p,s,m,w,b,f,z,A,q,x;f=a.parent();null!=e&&(f=f.closest(e));if(!f.length)throw"failed to find stick parent";z=function(){var c,b;c=parseInt(f.css("border-top-width"),10);b=parseInt(f.css("padding-top"),10);d=parseInt(f.css("padding-bottom"),
10);h=f.offset().top+c+b;v=f.height();c=a.is(".is_stuck")?q:a;y=c.offset().top-parseInt(c.css("margin-top"),10)-k;return l=c.outerHeight(!0)};z();if(l!==v)return m=a.css("float"),q=g("<div />").css({width:a.outerWidth(!0),height:l,display:a.css("display"),"vertical-align":a.css("vertical-align"),float:m}),p=s=!1,w=void 0,b=k,A=!1,x=function(){var c,g,n,e;n=t.scrollTop();null!=w&&(g=n-w);w=n;s?(e=n+l+b>v+h,p&&!e&&(p=!1,a.css({position:"fixed",bottom:"",top:b}).trigger("sticky_kit:unbottom")),n<y&&
(s=!1,b=k,"left"!==m&&"right"!==m||a.insertAfter(q),q.detach(),c={position:""},A&&(c.width=""),a.css(c).removeClass(r).trigger("sticky_kit:unstick")),u&&(c=t.height(),l>c&&!p&&(b-=g,b=Math.max(c-l,b),b=Math.min(k,b),a.css({top:b+"px"})))):n>y&&(s=!0,c={position:"fixed",top:b},"none"===m&&"block"===a.css("display")&&(c.width=a.width()+"px",A=!0),a.css(c).addClass(r).after(q),"left"!==m&&"right"!==m||q.append(a),a.trigger("sticky_kit:stick"));if(s&&(null==e&&(e=n+l+b>v+h),!p&&e))return p=!0,"static"===
f.css("position")&&f.css({position:"relative"}),a.css({position:"absolute",bottom:d,top:""}).trigger("sticky_kit:bottom")},t.on("scroll",x),setTimeout(x,0),g(document.body).on("sticky_kit:recalc",function(){z();return x()})};h=0;for(C=this.length;h<C;h++)d=this[h],B(g(d));return this}}).call(this);

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#sticker").stick_in_parent();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is position:absolute, and bottom:0, after you navigation stuck to the top (sticky kit adds style="top:0") and it gets stretched to the bottom of the page.

just add this function:

```
  $("#sticker").stick_in_parent()

  .on("sticky_kit:stick", function(e) {

      $(".navbar").removeClass("navbar-bottom");

  })
```

which does something when element "is sticky"

opposite to that one is:

```
 .on("sticky_kit:unstick", function(e) {

    //do something when "not sticky"

  });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/u6aNX/2/

If you want your navbar to goes back to "onload" position when you scroll up

```
.on("sticky_kit:unstick", function(e) {

   var top_bar = document.getElementById ("sticker");

   top_bar.style.top = "";

   $(".navbar").addClass("navbar-bottom");

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/u6aNX/3/